# Chromium Build Fails on Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, build, chromium

I am attempting to build Chromium for windows (using Visual Studio 2008 SP1) and it fails with about 37 errors. Here's a selection:

```
Error   1   error LNK2005: "wchar_t const * const switches::kProcessChannelID" (?kProcessChannelID@switches@@3QB_WB) already defined in ipc.lib(ipc_switches.obj)   common.lib  chrome_dll
Error   2   error LNK2005: "wchar_t const * const switches::kDebugChildren" (?kDebugChildren@switches@@3QB_WB) already defined in ipc.lib(ipc_switches.obj) common.lib  chrome_dll
Error   3   error LNK2005: "wchar_t const * const switches::kIPCUseFIFO" (?kIPCUseFIFO@switches@@3QB_WB) already defined in ipc.lib(ipc_switches.obj)   common.lib  chrome_dll
Error   4   fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found C:\Users\RCIX\src\chrome\Debug\chrome.dll   1   chrome_dll
```

Those errors are the only type of errors that how up but they pop up in about half a dozen projects. What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the symbols are defined in two places; ipc.lib (via ipc_switches.obj) and common.lib.  I am not familiar with Chromium at all, but I would guess that common.lib incorporates ipc.lib and the chrome_dll project is trying to link to both libs.  Try removing ipc.lib from the linker inputs.

Comment: Sadly i've long since given up on this, but it sounds reasonable... I'll accept this.

Comment: Why they do not write an article which is bullet proof?